# I am getting a error in the log, but the scripts do what I want

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am trying to do the following.

**SELECT** from **database** and echo, If there are less than 3 results, I want to **subtract** the amount of results from 3 and use an alternative SELECT string, The code works and does what I expect of it except for the error in the logs.

> PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   null given in

This error seems to be because the result is empty, How can I check how many rows in a result without getting an error when the table has no results.

```
$sqls="SELECT  * FROM xxx ORDER by xxx_id ASC LIMIT 0,3";
    $objRs = mysql_query($sqls);
```

The database works, the SQL query works, the row below this is the one giving me the error when I have a NULL result.  Is there another way to check the number of rows without getting the server pissed at me

```
    $count = mysql_num_rows($objRS);

        If (!empty($count)) { 
                    $pnb = 3;
            }   else {
                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($objRs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: You have different case of the last letter of $objRs when you use and initialize it.

Comment: please use mysqli or pdo - mysql is deprecated. example use of mysqli `(oop) $res = $conn->query($sql)` or `(procedural) $res= mysqli_query($conn, $sql)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Answer (score 4):

The code "works" by coincidence alone.  You have a typo:

```
$objRs
```

is not the same thing as

```
$objRS
```

Variable names are case-sensitive.  But the comparison you have set up doesn't actually check any results.  This:

```
!empty($count)
```

is just checking if `$count` has *any* value.  Which it does.  Whether that value is a positive number or not, your code doesn't care.  But it probably should...

Comment: Thank You David, I missed that and that seems to have done the trick, talk about not seeing the trees for the forest.